# How to use lazy loading in react-image-gallery?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am using react-image-gallery and the requirement is to implement a gallery that will load 100 images at a time.
So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

React-image-gallery provides a prop with the name of **lazyLoad** which accepts a Boolean value. Set it to true to achieve the lazyloading.

It would go like this

```
<ImageGallery 
    lazyload={true}
    items={images}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation (https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery) there is a `lazyLoad` prop on the component.